# 'Connection aborted' error while trying to send events to Azure Event Hub using java EventHubClient API

Tags: java, azure, azure-eventhub

I am trying to write a java publisher program, to send a single message to event hub. but, when i try to execute it i get a connection aborted error. I am using maven dependency specified in below link(azure-eventhubs) and version of 0.9.0 Below is the link i am trying to follow and the main method .

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-ephcs-getstarted

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        throws ServiceBusException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException, IOException {
    final String namespaceName = "<namespace name>";
    final String eventHubName = "<created with same name as namespace>";
    final String sasKeyName = "RootManageSharedAccessKey";
    final String sasKey = "<primary key from shared acccess policies>";

    ConnectionStringBuilder connStr = new ConnectionStringBuilder(namespaceName, eventHubName, sasKeyName, sasKey);

    byte[] payloadBytes = "Test AMQP message from JMS, Yaay it works".getBytes("UTF-8");
    EventData sendEvent = new EventData(payloadBytes);

    EventHubClient ehClient = EventHubClient.createFromConnectionStringSync(connStr.toString());
    ehClient.sendSync(sendEvent);
}
```

Here is the stacktrace of the error i get. Any help is appreciated.

```
  error[connection aborted]
  Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.ServiceBusException: connection aborted
    at com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.ExceptionUtil.toException(ExceptionUtil.java:93)
    at com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.MessagingFactory.onConnectionError(MessagingFactory.java:187)
    at com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.amqp.ConnectionHandler.onTransportError(ConnectionHandler.java:105)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.BaseHandler.handle(BaseHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.EventImpl.dispatch(EventImpl.java:108)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.dispatch(ReactorImpl.java:309)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.process(ReactorImpl.java:276)
    at com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.MessagingFactory$RunReactor.run(MessagingFactory.java:340)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Whenever I have connected to Service Bus endpoints from Java, I've used the full connection string.  I found this page (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/have-some-java-with-your-event-hub/) and it looks like there is a way to create the Connection using a connection string, instead of the ConnectionStringBuilder.  Perhaps try that?  I also though I read somewhere that Java clients couldn't use partitioned namespaces.  Is your namespace partitioned, and if so can you remove them?

Comment: Thanks, I did try specifying the complete connection string like you mentioned and i still get the same error. I even tried creating new event hub and specifying the new values but nothing seem to work. I didn't understand the partitioned namespaces part. My event hub is partitioned into 3 partitions and 3 days retention but event hub namespace doesn't have the partition property. During creation of namespace the only input required is Name, Pricing tier, Resource group and location. I don't see partitions for namespace.

Comment: There was a similar GitHub issue of Azure EventHub SDK for Java at the end of comment list of the [issue page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-java/issues/7). Per my experience, please check whether some firewall & anti-virus software prevent the amqp connection over SSL. If not, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I finally got it working. The isuee was firewall in my office. When i tried it from home system i had no issues.

Comment: @Hemanthmeka, OK, Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's definitely a firewall issue, you will need to use the below code which would help you in solving the connection issue when writing the data to EventHub.

Hope this helps!

```
final ConnectionStringBuilder connStr = new ConnectionStringBuilder()
                .setNamespaceName("Your namespace name")
                .setEventHubName("Your eventHub Name")
                .setSasKeyName("Enter the SAS key name")
                .setSasKey("SAS Key details");

        connStr.setTransportType(TransportType.AMQP_WEB_SOCKETS);
        ProxySelector.setDefault(new ProxySelector() {
            @Override
            public List<Proxy> select(URI uri) {
                LinkedList<Proxy> proxies = new LinkedList<>();
                proxies.add(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,
                        new InetSocketAddress("proxy information" ,port)));
                return proxies;
            }
            @Override
            public void connectFailed(URI uri, SocketAddress sa, IOException ioe) {
                // trace and follow up on why proxy server is down
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Summarized for the above comments, it seems like a similar GitHub issue of Azure EventHub SDK for Java at the end of comment list of the [issue page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-java/issues/7). 
However, per my experience, it seems that some firewall & anti-virus software prevent the amqp connection over SSL. And the fact as @Hemanthmeka said, the issue was caused by the firewall in his office.