# Getting EventHubException : Connection aborted when I create TWO instances of EventHubClient

Tags: java, azure, azure-eventhub

This is also not a duplicate of ['Connection aborted' error while trying to send events to Azure Event Hub using java EventHubClient API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905400/connection-aborted-error-while-trying-to-send-events-to-azure-event-hub-using) because the issue in this question was related to proxy. This is NOT an issue with my proxy settings as this code works for Singe Event hub client

My Question: Is it possible to have a Java Application which sends messages to TWO or more Event Hub Clients?

I am trying to publish/send event data to Multiple instances of Azure Event hubs.
I have provisioned TWO event hub namespaces and each namespace has its event hub.
I have in all TWO event hubs which have their own Connection Strings, SAS Keys and Namespaces and Names.
Since each event hub namespace can only support 20 Throughput units without manual intervention( service request), I am trying to find if I can send my data to Multiple Event hubs.
**I can see that my code works fine for SINGLE EventHubClient**. The moment, my code tries to create the second EventHubClient, I get this connection aborted exception.

I am using the sample code shared on azure's git hub at https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-send.md

I see the below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.EventHubException: connection aborted
at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.ExceptionUtil.toException(ExceptionUtil.java:59)
at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessagingFactory.onConnectionError(MessagingFactory.java:249)
at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.ConnectionHandler.onTransportError(ConnectionHandler.java:102)
at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.BaseHandler.handle(BaseHandler.java:191)
at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.EventImpl.dispatch(EventImpl.java:108)
at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.dispatch(ReactorImpl.java:324)
at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.process(ReactorImpl.java:291)
at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessagingFactory$RunReactor.run(MessagingFactory.java:445)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any pointers/inputs will be highly appreciated.
Here is the relevant code:

```
public class Sender {

private static final String EVENTHUB_NS1= "TT";
private static final String EVENTHUB1= "TT";
private static final String SAS_KEY_NAME1= "RootManageSharedAccessKey";
private static final String SAS_KEY_VAL1= "SECRET1";

private static final String EVENTHUB_NS2= "TT1";
private static final String EVENTHUB2= "TT1";
private static final String SAS_KEY_NAME2= "RootManageSharedAccessKey";
private static final String SAS_KEY_VAL2= "SECRET2";


private EventData getEventData(int eventDataPrefix) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    String msgData = "<=>"+eventDataPrefix + "<=>"+"TEST MESSAGE..";
    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    byte [] data =gson.toJson(msgData).getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
    EventData ed = EventData.create(data);
    return ed;
}
public static final int MAX_BATCH_SIZE=100;
private List<EventData> getBatchOfEvents() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    List<EventData> events = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_BATCH_SIZE; i ++){
        events.add(getEventData(i));
    }
    return events;
}
private List<String> getConnectionStrings(){
    List<String> connStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    ConnectionStringBuilder csBldr1 = new ConnectionStringBuilder();
    csBldr1.setNamespaceName(EVENTHUB_NS1);
    csBldr1.setEventHubName(EVENTHUB1);
    csBldr1.setSasKeyName(SAS_KEY_NAME1);
    csBldr1.setSasKey(SAS_KEY_VAL1);

    ConnectionStringBuilder csbldr2 = new ConnectionStringBuilder();
    csbldr2.setNamespaceName(EVENTHUB_NS2);
    csbldr2.setEventHubName(EVENTHUB2);
    csbldr2.setSasKeyName(SAS_KEY_NAME2);
    csbldr2.setSasKey(SAS_KEY_VAL2);

    connStrings.add(csBldr1.toString());
    connStrings.add(csbldr2.toString());
    return connStrings;
}

private List<EventHubClient> getEHClients() throws IOException, EventHubException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    List<EventHubClient> ehClients = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Starting getEhCLients..");

    for( String connStr: getConnectionStrings()){

        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        //The second iteration of for loop gives the EventHubException
        EventHubClient client= EventHubClient.createSync(connStr, executorService);


        ehClients.add(client);
        System.out.println("EH CONNSTR::"+connStr);
    }

    return ehClients;
}


private void sendBatch( List<EventData> events) throws IOException, EventHubException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    List<EventHubClient> ehClients = getEHClients();
    if( ehClients.size() <=0) {
        System.out.println("NO EH CLients.. to send..");
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < events.size();i++){
        EventData data = events.get(i);
        int ehClientIndex = i % ehClients.size();
        EventHubClient client = ehClients.get(ehClientIndex);
        client.sendSync(data);
        System.out.print("MsgSent:"+ehClientIndex);
    }
    System.out.println("\nDone");
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, EventHubException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    Sender sender = new Sender();
    List<EventData> events = sender.getBatchOfEvents();
    sender.sendBatch(events);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting use case, I could try to reproduce from my side. My guess is that EventHubClient has some static field, which will be shared by multiple instance, this might cause your issue.

Besides that, I want to understand why use two namespace, how to about one namespace with higher throughput. One namespace is like a cluster. Actually, I'm from Spring Cloud Azure, and try to improve Java experience on Azure. Feel free to try our event hub binder. https://github.com/Microsoft/spring-cloud-azure